# Create multiple bivariate plots in R

Tags: r

Having a data frame `res`, with

```
> colnames(res)
[1] "alpha"     "L1"        "rskc"      "CER"       "clustSize" "nonZero"
```

With this code

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(3,2))
for (z in c("CER", "clustSize", "nonZero")) {
  f <- factor(res$L1)
  plot(res[,z] ~ alpha, data=res, ylab=z, col=f)
  for (y in res$L1) {
    sres <- subset(res, L1==y)
    lines(sres$alpha, sres[,z], col=match(y, levels(f)))
  }
  
  f <- factor(res$alpha)
  plot(res[,z] ~ L1, data=res, ylab=z, col=f)
  for (y in res$alpha) {
    sres <- subset(res, alpha==y)
    lines(sres$L1, sres[,z], col=match(y, levels(f)))
  }
  
}; par(op)
```

I created this graph: [image: graph1]

I'd like to have a graph like the following (which was created with `par(mfrow=c(3,2), mar=rep(2,4))`), with the less space between the subplots, but with the possibility of showing the x-axis label of the bottom subplots and the y-axis label of the subplots on the left. How would you do that?

[image]